Is integration physical, but differentiation is not?
There are electrical (e.g. analogue computers), and even mechanical (ball-pen) methods to generate the integral of a given function.
On the other hand, naively differentiating a physically given function would not make any sense since for very small intervals, the errors would be larger than the fluctuation of the function values.
Yet integration and differentiation are closely related to each other.
So is it true that while you can integrate "mechanically", you cannot differentiate "mechanically"?

And yet analog computers have elements that do differentiation.

I don't know enough about electrical engineering and circuit design to properly write an answer, but there literally is a circuit known as a differentiator which approximates the temporal rate of change of its input, with some limitations.

The speedometer in your car is a mechanical differentiator (if your car is old enough).

I don't get the closing rationale at all. Not opinion based, it is asking for any examples physical differentiaton, which were provided.

To measure the rate of change in something, you need only find a physical relationship that relates a measureable quantity to a rate of change in another quantity.
For example, the voltage $V$ across an inductor $L$ is proportional to the rate of change in current through it:
$$ V=L~{dI\over dt}$$
If you set up a circuit that measures this voltage at any given time, your are directly measuring the derivative of the current.
Now, if you create a measuring device where some quantity of interest (temperature, pressure, rotation rate, force) directly causes a current $I$ to flow proportional to its magnitude, your inductor voltage is the rate of change in the quantity of interest.

Your car's speedometer operates similarly

Since $\vec F = m \dot{\vec v}$ if you apply a known velocity profile and measure the force then you have done mechanical differentiation.

The derivative of a function is the slope of its graph. A physical example might be the function of the height of a line painted on the surface of the earth.
If the surface is smooth, the slope taken from a small interval will be similar to the slope taken from a larger interval and the true slope. If the surface is rough, then the slope changes quickly over a short distance. You need really short intervals to get good approximations.
If your measurement process has noise, you are not measuring the derivative. The derivative still represents the slope of the line. It is just hard to measure.


Is integration physical, but differentiation is not?

Not true. In numerical differentiation methods, $f'(x)$ is just :
$$ f'(x)=\lim _{\Delta x\to 0}{\frac {f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}} \tag 1$$
So you can build a computational device, which uses this procedure of numerical function change $\Delta f(x)$ estimation using smaller and smaller $\Delta x$ argument in (1) until you see that (1) given expression converges to some final function, like pictured here - finding derivative $\ln'(x)$ :

(Drawn with Desmos graphing calculator). Hence conclusion is that for finding function derivative you don't need to monitor exact effect of infinitesimal changes, just a lookup where (1) goes when you narrow your change $\Delta x$ by continuous fashion and then checking if it converges  to some function.
For that you only need to evaluate error of $|f_{n+1}'(x)-f_{n}'(x)|$ and see if it approaches zero. That's it, nowadays any decent calculator can do this. So, it's very physical.

You can represent the derivative as an integral by taking the inverse Fourier transform of $i\omega$ times the Fourier transform, so I don't think this idea is self-consistent. (In addition the correct objections noted in other answers).
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} (i \omega) e^{i \omega t}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt' f(t')e^{-i \omega t'} = i \int \frac{d \omega}{2\pi} dt'\ \omega f(t') e^{i \omega(t-t')}
$$
Your idea would imply that the left hand side is "unphysical" but the right hand side is "physical."

In any practical analogue/mechanical context there is a low pass filter in one way or another, be it by design or simply due to the intrinsic physical characteristics of the system (i.e. mass).
Differentiation of sufficiently band-limited signals will not have a problematic blow up: this is most easily seen with Fourier analysis as per @Andrew's answer: the effect of differentiation in Fourier space is to multiply by $i\omega$: this can only cause a divergence if the function being differentiated has a Fourier transform that decays slower than this linear growth.
So yes, while in principle for an unfiltered signal differentiation can lead to problematic blowups (e.g. white noise), this can be worked around with appropriate low-pass filtering.
Also note that an analogous problem can arise with mechanical integration: a noise floor will gradually grow the integrated signal beyond the bounds of the integrator, so in practice for signal processing applications a high pass filter is needed to avoid this (seen in Fourier transform terms as the divergence of $1/i\omega$ as $\omega\to 0$)
